# Why do I get a "ValueError: Shape mismatch" when using CategoricalCrossentropy loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, neural-network

I created a simple  TensorFlow model (no convolution layers) using the MNIST dataset. I initially used `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` loss function and it worked fine. I created a nearly identical model this time using `CategoricalCrossentropy` loss and changed the labels to one-hot encoding:

```py
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist_data

# scale data:
x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255

# create one-hot encoding:
y_train_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y_train, 10).numpy()
y_test_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y_test, 10).numpy()

# print shapes:
# each image is 28x28; 60,000 examples; 10 possible output values:
print(x_train.shape)  # (60000, 28, 28)
print(y_train.shape)  # (60000, 10)
```

```py
model = Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model_history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train_one_hot,
    epochs=20
)
```

However, I'm not able to even train the model as I get an error: `ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (320,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (32, 10)).` I don't really understand what shape is wrong or why.

**Edit:**
I forgot to show how I set `mnist_data`:

```py
mnist_data = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all I did was change the first line of code

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

It trained as it should.  Note you have this line of code

```
print(y_train.shape)  # (60000, 10)
```

the dimension is not (60000,10) it is (60000). After you one hot encode it it will be (60000,10)

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I did load the mnist data like you did (except I load the original mnist set, not the fashion mnist). Anyway, I found out the problem: I had a lot of different models all on a single notebook and the data (that was being reused) got transformed/reshaped somewhere along the way. So, you're right -- there was nothing wrong with the model itself.